# Having trouble with radio buttons forgetting its state when using React-Window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-window

I have follow a couple of [examples](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/virtualized-rows) using react-table and react-window so far so good, but I need the table to have select boxes to select individual or grouped rows as well as a radio-like button to be able to toggle information for a row, I manage to implement this but when I scroll up or down the selected radio button looses its selected state, as shown below
[image]

As you can see when I select a row its ID is displayed below the table but when I scroll and move the row away from the view the radio button looses its checked state.

I have an example of the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-window-multiple-selection-tools-qsth1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you must update your **RadioCheckbox** component

```
const RadioCheckbox = ({ cell, checked, handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="radio"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={cell.row.id}
      checked={checked}
    />
  );
};
```

and then, you must add a function to handle your change in **App** component and change your default state of **selectedRadio**

```
const [selectedRadio, setSelectedRadio] = useState([]);

const handleSelectedRadioChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    if (selectedRadio.includes(currentTarget.value)) {
      setSelectedRadio(
        selectedRadio.filter((item) => item === currentTarget.value)
      );
    } else {
      setSelectedRadio(currentTarget.value);
    }
 };
```

and for the last step update the dependencies of your columns useMemo in App with **[selectedRadio]** and you must update your **Cell** render

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        id: "radio",
        Header: "on/off",
        Cell: (props) =>
          notAllowedRows.includes(props.cell.row.index) ? null : (
            <div>
              <RadioCheckbox
                cell={props.cell}
                checked={selectedRadio.includes(props.cell.row.id)}
                handleChange={handleSelectedRadioChange}
              />
            </div>
          ),
        width: 60
      },
      {
        Header: "Row Index",
        accessor: (row, i) => i,
        width: 95
      },
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "lastName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age",
        width: 50
      },
      {
        Header: "Visits",
        accessor: "visits",
        width: 60
      }
    ],
    [selectedRadio]
  );
```

Comment: After applying your suggestions the radio buttons don't show the checked state, but they do update the number above the table, any ideas

Comment: Oh my bad, add selectedRadio to your useMemo dependencies, I'll edit my answer

Comment: By changing `setSelectedRadio([currentTarget.value]);` in the `else` statement on the `handleSelectedRadioChange` method works perfectly, the array was keeping a history of all the previous selected row ids and it didn't behave properly, thank you!